# jQuery responsive multi-paged menu mouseover/leave interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

level menu with a unconventional html markup due to the responsive nature of the project. That means I cannot use nested **ul** and **li** like one usually does when creating nested menus.

I have created a fiddle which on mouseover loads the correct next menu but on mouseleave the menus stay.

**I want the menus to act like a hover interaction and be hidden once the cursor leaves the correspondent sub-level**

**http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/pqbvkuoy/**

```
$('.level2').hide();
$('.level3').hide();


$('.level1').find('ul .active').mouseover( function(){
    $('.level2').show();
});

$('.level2').find('ul .active').mouseover( function(){
    $('.level3').show();
});
```

Thank you

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: adding that just so you can look into it more and maybe before I submit my own answer you have a better answer

Comment: Your menu design should be nested uls. Because of being responsive does not mean it can not be nested. Means you would need to alter the CSS in a different manner.

Comment: I see what you mean but using nested uls do not allow for fluid or percent-based layouts.

Comment: @epascarello is right responsive can't be a reason to avoid the nested ul you just need to think better the way can work

Comment: *"nested uls do not allow for fluid or percent-based layouts."* UM, yes it can.

Comment: I appreciate your help and I would like to believe you. But unless I see an example of nested ul li that are fluid – I wont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** event and **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**. Try this:

```
$('.level1').find('ul .active').hover( function(){
        $('.level2').toggle();
});
```

Check this <kbd>[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqbvkuoy/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Problem is that is not going to work with the OPs design. Impossible to click on the secondary menu.

Comment: Yep @epascarello you are right... can be solved with more code on Jquery or just with a line on CSS http://jsfiddle.net/pqbvkuoy/3/

Comment: @SebastianGraz if you feel like keeping your design use this one. BUT do not use straight toggle. Use `toggleClass()` and do everything with CSS. This way you avoid `!important` which is the best way to go about this. If you use `!important` you're not trying hard enough to get the best solution.

Comment: Yes that does make sense. I try to avoid !important at all costs

Comment: @SebastianGraz of course you can avoid !important but in this case is just for the hover ... since Jquery define inline styles ... even if you use toggleClass on the level2 it will desappear when you try to hover it. You may need another lines of jquery to acomplish that